# Android, line width, pixel size

Tags: android, line, pixel

Using Android canvas draw commands:

If I set stroke = 0 or stroke =1 and draw horizontal line, the line pixels are two pixels high. If I set stroke = 2, the pixels are also two pixels high but are brighter.

If I draw single pixels, the pixels are a 2x2 matrix for stroke = 0 or stroke = 1. If the stroke = 2, I also get a 2x2 matrix but with brighter pixels.

What must I do to get lines that are only one pixel tall?
What must I do to get pixels that are one and only pixel?

Note: The devices that am using have screen sizes of 480 x 800 or greater.

```
Paint thePaint = new Paint();                   
thePaint.setARGB(a, r, g, b);                           
thePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
thePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL );
thePaint.setStrokeWidth(0);
canvas.drawLine(x1,y1,x2,y2, thePaint);
```

Comment: according to the docs, strokeWidth of 0 should be 1-pixel no matter what... could you provide some code showing how you are creating your Paint object and how you are drawing to the Canvas?

Comment: Code added. Yes, that is what the documentation says. That is not the reality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I communicated with The Roman Guy @Google about this issue. He said the AntiAlias need to be turned off in addition of setting stroke = 0. My testing showed that he is right. The Google documentation does not current reflect this requirement. This code works.

```
Paint thePaint = new Paint();                   
thePaint.setARGB(a, r, g, b);                           
thePaint.setAntiAlias(false);
thePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE );
thePaint.setStrokeWidth(0);
canvas.drawLine(x1,y1,x2,y2, thePaint);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to replace the line

```
thePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
```

with this instead:

```
thePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
```

Comment: are your x1, y1, x2, y2 values all integer values?  You can get funny aliasing when you have fractional values.